# 'Rare are those books you wish shouldn't end'. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: word-usage

Is this sentence meaningful and complete? Should I use 'that' before 'you wish' or is it okay like that? Is 'shouldnt end' depicting that I want the book to keep on going like an endless tuft of pages?

Comment: *Rare are those books you wish **wouldn't** end.*

Comment: It's a *very* stylised construction. Unless your command of English is so good you don't need to use this site anyway, you probably shouldn't write or speak like this. The normal word order is *[Those] books [that] you wish wouldn't end are rare.*